# Preventing changing voice extension automatically to "bin"

Tags: ios, swift, upload, alamofire, nsurlsession

By using the following code, I am trying to upload a "caf" file to a server using Alamofire:

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            if let voiceData = try? Data(contentsOf: voiceURL) {
                multipartFormData.append(voiceData, withName: "file", fileName: "file.ogg", mimeType: "audio/ogg")
                for (key, value) in parameters {
                    multipartFormData.append((value.data(using: .utf8)) ?? Data(), withName: key)
                }
            }
        }, to: "url", method: .post, headers: nil, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult{
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.response { [weak self] response in
                    print(response)
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print("Error: \(encodingError)")
            }
        })
```

As you can see, mimeType is set to "file.ogg", but when uploading to a PHP server, it automatically changes to ".bin" format. I have also tried using NSURLSession directly without Alamofire, but that didn't help either.

I would be happy if you can help me in this regard.

- iOS 11 API, Swift 3

Comment: This looks like a problem with the remote server, not the client. Suggest you review how the PHP code is handling the uploaded file instead.

Comment: @brandonscript Android client is working as normal, and there is no problem in it. Even iOS app uploads other types of files currently. The only problem is in audio files.